# Set Thread.CurrentPrincipal in Owin

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, owin

Is there a good way to set my custom Principal to let business logic access full information about user that made a request to web api?

I've tried these:

1. Setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal in MessageHandler is overridden and later in ApiController I get a ClaimsPrincipal setted my Owin middleware
2. Creating BaseController : ApiController and trying to set Thread.CurrentPrincipal in ExecuteAsync didn't work because I always get Request.GetOwinContext.Authentication.User.....IsAuthenticated = false, though later in ApiController method call it is set to ClaimsIdentity again